# Asynchronously load images to a navigation flyout or best way to load images

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a Large navigation flyout menu with images displaying the items.

its working fine however the page load time is a little slower since i have more images to display.

my example code

```
<ul>
<li>
<a>Cars<a/>
<div class="flyOutMenu">
<img src="img/car1.png" />
<div>Mustang</div>
<div>Honda</div>
<div>BMW</div>
</div>
<li>
</ul>
```

navigations can have 40 images

any way i can load the image faster via jquery? or handler

Any idea or links would be great thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to start be recomending you optimize the images. Make sure that the dimenttions are what you need them to be and that they are not being resized by CSS. Also use an image editing progarm to fine tune the optimisation. You may not need "Maximised" jpgs.

Also look at [sprites](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/) for the images. 1 Large download is often faster than many smaller ones. Particlarly 40 images!

I would avoid anything that loads the image "on demand" as ther will be lag the first time the user "Calls" it

See http://csssprites.com/ for a tool that may help you with sprites.

Comment: thank you I'm currently working on sprites however it is not going to be easy.

Answer (score 1):

Few tips for Loading Images faster.

1. Always define Alt, Height and Width attribute in image tag. This helps loading image faster.

   ```
    <img src="img/car1.png" alt="myimage"  height="60" width="60"/>
   ```
2. Try combining multiple images to one and use css sprite when using in css
3. Try compressing the images to gzip, almost all modern browsers can understand that. images with lower size will load faster.
4. Avoid invalid links of images(when giving 404 for image  for invalid image url.)

Comment: ya i had that in my navigation the problem i have around 40 images in my fly out the page will make 40 calls to the image server.

Answer (score 0):

Make the images background images of a div. the div will load quickly, while the images will come in later as bandwidth permits. Place a background color on the image div while the images are loading, and set a width and height for the image div.

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a>Cars<a/>
    <div class="flyOutMenu">
      <div style="background-image: url(img/car1.png); 
           height: 200px; width: 200px; background-color: black;" />
      <div>Mustang</div>
      <div>Honda</div>
      <div>BMW</div>
    </div>
  <li>
</ul>
```

This doesn't make the images load faster, but does allow the user to start interacting with the page before the images arrive.

If you are looking for a way to pre-load the images, you could use css, javascript or ajax calls. Here is a good link: http://perishablepress.com/3-ways-preload-images-css-javascript-ajax/